# How to exclude autogenerated methods from Parcelable in Jacoco reports?

Tags: android, kotlin, parcelable, jacoco

I'm using Jacoco for creating a test coverage report and I also use the  Parcelize Android extension plugin to create the methods needed for the Parcelables.

When I create the test reports the auto-generated functions are also appearing in the test coverages (e.g. `createFromParcel(Parcel))` and of course they don't have any coverage.

How can I exclude those functions from my reports?

Answer (score 1):

I've looked how to do this for a while, and apparently Jacoco does ignore the auto-generated code as of version 0.8.2, but for this particular case, the CREATOR static field needed for the Parcelable interface to work is not ignored. So I had to test it. Though I couldn't easily find it accessible as a static field of my Parcelable class, so I had to get it using reflection:

```
val yourParcelableClassCreator = YourParcelableClass::class.java.getField("CREATOR").get(null) as Parcelable.Creator<YourParcelableClass>
```

After that, you can test its `createFromParcel` method normally and it will be reflected in your jacoco coverage.